# Terminal says : ' Not Created By QtDesigner'

Tags: python, terminal, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying to convert a `resources.qrc` file to `resources_rc.py` file in order to use it in python.

When I write `'pyuic5.exe .\resources.qrc -o .\resources_rc.py'` after opened the folder in terminal.
And it throws that one : `Error in input file: not created by Qt Designer`

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

`pyuic5` is typically used to convert Qt Designer UI files (.ui) to Python files, not resource files.

To convert a Qt resource file (.qrc) to a Python file (.py), you should use the `pyrcc5` utility instead.

```
pyrcc5.exe resources.qrc -o resources_rc.py
```

After running this command, you should be able to use the generated `resources_rc.py` file in your Python code to access the resources defined in your `.qrc file`.